# How to zip a directory in linux excluding a single file?

Tags: linux

I would like to zip a directory and I am able to do so with

```
zip -r zip_file_name directory
```

however, I would like exclude a single file in the directory from the zip file. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `zip -r zip_file_name directory -x \excluded_file.extension`---Probably this will help!

Answer (score 1):

Enter the directory which you want to zip. Then:

```
find . -not -name "file_to_exclude" | zip zip_file_name -@
```

The command above will create zip_file_name.zip in directory itself.

To create zip at a particular path, Enter the directory which you want to zip. Then:

```
find . -not -name "file_to_exclude" | zip ~/ParticularPath/zip_file_name -@
```

From linux man page for zip:

-@ file lists.  If a file list is specified as -@ [Not on MacOS], zip takes the list of input files from standard input instead of from the command line.  For example,

zip -@ foo

will store the files listed one per line on stdin in foo.zip.

Under Unix, this option can be used to powerful effect in conjunction with the find command.  For example, to archive all the C source files in  the  current directory and its subdirectories:

find . -name "*.[ch]" -print | zip source -@

Comment: `find . -not -name "file_to_exclude" -exec zip file_name {} \;` should work too.

Comment: Small warning: if you have multiple file with the same name in the hierarchy this will exclude *all* of them.